# DataTable to JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-2.0, datatable

I recently needed to serialize a datatable to JSON.  Where I'm at we're still on .Net 2.0, so I can't use the JSON serializer in .Net 3.5.  I figured this must have been done before, so I went looking online and [found](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNET_DataTable_to_JSON.aspx) a [number](http://www.dennydotnet.com/post/A-DataTable-Serializer-for-ASPNET-AJAX.aspx) of [different](http://schotime.net/blog/index.php/2008/07/27/dataset-datatable-to-json/) [options](https://web.archive.org/web/20200204000610/http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2008/03/22/120709.aspx).  Some of them depend on an additional library, which I would have a hard time pushing through here.  Others require first converting to `List<Dictionary<>>`, which seemed a little awkward and needless.  Another treated all values like a string.  For one reason or another I couldn't really get behind any of them, so I decided to roll my own, which is posted below.

As you can see from reading the `//TODO` comments, it's incomplete in a few places.  This code is already in production here, so it does "work" in the basic sense.  The places where it's incomplete are places where we know our production data won't currently hit it (no timespans or byte arrays in the db).  The reason I'm posting here is that I feel like this can be a little better, and I'd like help finishing and improving this code.  Any input welcome.

*Note that this capability is built into .Net 3.5 and later, and so the only reason to use this code today is if you're still limited to .Net 2.0. Even then, JSON.Net has become the goto library for this kind of thing.*

```
public static class JSONHelper
{
    public static string FromDataTable(DataTable dt)
    {
        string rowDelimiter = "";

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("[");
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            result.Append(rowDelimiter);
            result.Append(FromDataRow(row));
            rowDelimiter = ",";
        }
        result.Append("]");

        return result.ToString();
    }

    public static string FromDataRow(DataRow row)
    {
        DataColumnCollection cols = row.Table.Columns;
        string colDelimiter = "";

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("{");       
        for (int i = 0; i < cols.Count; i++)
        { // use index rather than foreach, so we can use the index for both the row and cols collection
            result.Append(colDelimiter).Append("\"")
                  .Append(cols[i].ColumnName).Append("\":")
                  .Append(JSONValueFromDataRowObject(row[i], cols[i].DataType));

            colDelimiter = ",";
        }
        result.Append("}");
        return result.ToString();
    }

    // possible types:
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(VS.80).aspx
    private static Type[] numeric = new Type[] {typeof(byte), typeof(decimal), typeof(double), 
                                     typeof(Int16), typeof(Int32), typeof(SByte), typeof(Single),
                                     typeof(UInt16), typeof(UInt32), typeof(UInt64)};

    // I don't want to rebuild this value for every date cell in the table
    private static long EpochTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks;

    private static string JSONValueFromDataRowObject(object value, Type DataType)
    {
        // null
        if (value == DBNull.Value) return "null";

        // numeric
        if (Array.IndexOf(numeric, DataType) > -1)
            return value.ToString(); // TODO: eventually want to use a stricter format. Specifically: separate integral types from floating types and use the "R" (round-trip) format specifier

        // boolean
        if (DataType == typeof(bool))
            return ((bool)value) ? "true" : "false";

        // date -- see https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/dates-and-json
        if (DataType == typeof(DateTime))       
            return "\"\\/Date(" + new TimeSpan(((DateTime)value).ToUniversalTime().Ticks - EpochTicks).TotalMilliseconds.ToString() + ")\\/\"";

        // TODO: add Timespan support
        // TODO: add Byte[] support

        //TODO: this would be _much_ faster with a state machine
        //TODO: way to select between double or single quote literal encoding
        //TODO: account for database strings that may have single \r or \n line breaks
        // string/char  
        return "\"" + value.ToString().Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace(Environment.NewLine, @"\n").Replace("\"", @"\""") + "\"";
    }
}
```

**Update:**
This is old now, but I wanted to point out something about how this code handles dates. The format I used made sense at the time, for the exact rationale in the commented url. However, that rationale includes the following:

> To be perfectly honest, JSON Schema does solve the problem by making it possible to "subtype" a string as a date literal, but this is still work in progress and it will take time before any significant adoption is reached.

Well, time has passed. Today, it's okay to just use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date format. I'm not gonna bother changing the code, 'cause really: this is ancient. Just go use JSON.Net.

Comment: I found this: http://www.bramstein.com/projects/xsltjson/
You can convert your datatable to xml and use a xslt stylesheet to convert the xml to json. It is more a workaround than a real solution.

Comment: If this were asked today, it'd belong on the code review stack exchange instead. I've flagged it to be moved there, but the only reason it came to my attention is that it just earned a"Famous Question" Gold Badge. It'd suck to lose that view count in the migration.

Comment: I think this would be too old to migrate. It can live on here if you're ok with that?

Comment: I don't mind either way, just thinking about best fit. I've had other old stuff moved.

Comment: Great code there. Very helpful and straightforward.

Comment: Why is this still getting votes? .Net 2 is 8 years old now, and later versions convert to json out of the box. **There's no good reason to need anything like this anymore**. Also, FWIW, I know now what was bothering me with the original code: I should have been asking for a string as an argument passed my functions (or in a constructor) and writing my json strings to that straem with any eye to letting asp.net programmers pass the Response.Output stream. That should _greatly_ improve performance/scalability.

Comment: This is funny. Closed as a duplicate of a question asked four years later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would it help you convince your bosses to install a library if it's Microsoft's [AJAX extensions for .NET 2.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20100906013249/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en)?

Included in them is [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavascriptSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8), which is used in Step 4 of the [last link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200204000610/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/shahed/archive/2008/03/22/120709.aspx) in your post.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without installing additional libraries ?