# How to Pass System.Data.DataTable to JQuery file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable

I have a DataTable in PageLoad, I need to pass to it to a JQuery file to generate the BingMap contents

```
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
 {
    DataTable dt = dtLocations;
 }
```

my JQuery file is Included in `.ascx` page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/BingMap/BingMapJS.js" ></script>
```

Need to send this "dt" to JQuery file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table);
```

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm

Answer (score 0):

Most of jQuery libraries accept Json as data format to process, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546121/datatable-to-json-using-jquery) approach to convert your `DataTable` into Json result and then pass that to Bing JS library to process.