# How to convert datatable to json string using json.net?

Tags: c#, json, datatable, json.net

How to convert datatable to json using json.net? Any suggestion... I ve downloaded the necessary binaries... Which class should i use to get the conversion of my datatable to json?
Thus far used this method to get json string by passing my datatable...

```
public string GetJSONString(DataTable table)
    {
        StringBuilder headStrBuilder = new StringBuilder(table.Columns.Count * 5); //pre-allocate some space, default is 16 bytes
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            headStrBuilder.AppendFormat("\"{0}\" : \"{0}{1}¾\",", table.Columns[i].Caption, i);
        }
        headStrBuilder.Remove(headStrBuilder.Length - 1, 1); // trim away last ,

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(table.Rows.Count * 5); //pre-allocate some space
        sb.Append("{\"");
        sb.Append(table.TableName);
        sb.Append("\" : [");
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string tempStr = headStrBuilder.ToString();
            sb.Append("{");
            for (int j = 0; j < table.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                table.Rows[i][j] = table.Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace("'", "");
                tempStr = tempStr.Replace(table.Columns[j] + j.ToString() + "¾", table.Rows[i][j].ToString());
            }
            sb.Append(tempStr + "},");
        }
        sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1); // trim last ,
        sb.Append("]}");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Now i thought of using json.net but dont know where to get started....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451460/datatable-to-json

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table, Formatting.Indented);
```

Edit: You don't need indented formatting, of course, but it makes it nice and readable.

Comment: How do I iterate the resulting Json with JQuery?

Comment: Is there a way to convert XML hierarchical to a DataTable, flattening it out?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe it could help

**Original version**

```
public static class DataTableToJson
{
    public static JArray ToJson(this System.Data.DataTable source)
    {
        JArray result = new JArray();
        JObject row;
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in source.Rows)
        {
            row = new JObject();
            foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in source.Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), JToken.FromObject(dr[col]));
            }
            result.Add(row);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Edited Version**

There is a intermediate step because I needed to have a dictionary

```
public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> ToDictionary(this DataTable table)
{
    string[] columns = table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(c=>c.ColumnName).ToArray();
    IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>  result = table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            .Select(dr => columns.ToDictionary(c => c, c=> dr[c]));
    return result;
}
```

You can add `JsonConverter.SerializeObject(result);`, or another json serializer to get json string.

This is similar to @Hasan Javaid post

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
private static string DataTableToJson(DataTable dataTable)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var rows = (from DataRow d in dataTable.Rows
        select dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => d[col])).ToList();

    rows.AddRange(from DataRow d in dataTable.Rows
        select dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToDictionary(col => col.ColumnName, col => d[col]));
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```