# Iterate DataTable serialized through Json.Net in jQuery

Tags: .net, jquery, json, json.net

I found this awesome tip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979922/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-string-using-json-net) at how to serialize a .Net `DataTable` into a Json String using Json.Net with the following code:

```
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dtProdEv, Formatting.Indented);
```

I get the following result back:

```
[
  {
    "Col1": 2,
    "Col2": "\/Date(1292724000000-0200)\/",
    "Col3": 0,
    "Col4": 1,
    "Col5": "\/Date(1292772960760-0200)\/",
    "Col6": null,
    "Col7": null,
    "Col8": 0.0000,
    "Col9": 0,
    "Col10": 1
  },
  {
    "Col1": 2,
    "Col2": "\/Date(1292724000000-0200)\/",
    "Col3": 0,
    "Col4": 2,
    "Col5": "\/Date(1292773781763-0200)\/",
    "Col6": 3,
    "Col7": 1,
    "Col8": 0.0000,
    "Col9": 0,
    "Col10": 2
  }
]
```

My question is how can I iterate through this result using JQuery? I parse it into an Object using `parseJSON`, but then I'm stumped.
Tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.each` to iterate through the whole array.

[See the live demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/zainshaikh/fVEhq/2/)

```
// loop through the array of objects.
$.each(data ,function(i,item){

    // document.write(item["Col7"]); // print specific property


    // loop through the properties of each object.
    $.each(item, function(j, child){

        document.write(child); // print all the childs

    });

});
```