# Why Session variable gets update?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, dataset

I have been reading a xls file using `ExcelDataReader` and putting the complete `DataTable` in `Session`  variable with following code

```
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet(true,Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameter), 20);                
if (result.Tables.Count > 0)
   {                  
       if (result.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
         {                       
            Session["CellDirData"] = result.Tables[0]; 
         }
   }
```

In some other function i am getting this `DataTable` from `Session` Variable using following code

```
 DataTable dtTemp = (DataTable) Session["CellDirData"];                                   
 dtTemp.Rows.RemoveAt(0); // Removing first row from local variable dtTemp
```

When i am removing first row from local variable `dtTemp`, it also update the `Session` variable ie now both `dtTemp` and `Session["CellDirData"]` has 19 rows.

My question is why `Session` get update while i am playing with local variable only ?

Comment: Check order of events and where all places you are setting session.

Comment: Please read on http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx If you need a copy use  [DataTable.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel welcome your suggestion. But here i am not setting  session variable which may cause updation due to change in reference variable. I am getting the session into local variable.

Comment: `DataTable` is a class (reference type), which means that it will be copied by reference. So if you update one, you're actually modifying the original reference. Please read the differences between value types and reference types. Everything will be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because default session state mode is `InProc` (in-process). That is, you're creating references that point to the same `DataTable` object, since in-process means also *in-memory*.

Or in other words: your session, class fields and local variables share same sandboxed environment and memory and this means that creating new session state keys is almost the same as declaring new references (class fields and local variables).

See session [state modes article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) to learn more about available modes and their details.

If you want to store a session key in some state and continue editing the source object without affecting the stored one, you should *serialize* it to XML or JSON (or any other serialization format). See this other Q&A here on StackOverflow: [How to convert datatable to json string using json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979922/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-string-using-json-net)