# Convert DataTable to JSON with key per row

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datatable, json.net

I thought the following would be a pretty common task and assumed there would be an easy solution for it, but i can't find one.

If I have a datatable in the following structure.

```
ID  Name    Active
ID1 John    TRUE
ID2 Bill    FALSE
```

I would like to serialize it as a JSON object where the ID column is a node in the JSON object like:

```
[
    {
        "ID1": {
            "Name": "John",
            "Active": "True"
        },
        "ID2": {
            "Name": "Bill",
            "Active": "False"
        }
    }
]
```

I looked into JSON.NET but could not get it to work. 
Edit: I'm using C#

Comment: This won't happen just by itself. What language are you working in?

Comment: Hmm right forgot to mention C#, thx.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451460/datatable-to-json

Comment: And this: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Sep/03/DataTable-JSON-Serialization-in-JSONNET-and-JavaScriptSerializer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is quite simple with JSON.NET. Just convert your data table into the equivalent dictionary of dictionaries:

```
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>> DatatableToDictionary(DataTable dt, string id)
{
    var cols = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.ColumnName != id);
    return dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
             .ToDictionary(r => r[id].ToString(), 
                           r => cols.ToDictionary(c => c.ColumnName, c => r[c.ColumnName]));
}
```

Then call:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DatatableToDictionary(dt, "ID"), Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Here's the full test:

```
var dt = new DataTable("MyTable");
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Active");

dt.LoadDataRow(new[] {"ID1", "John", "True"}, true);
dt.LoadDataRow(new[] {"ID2", "Bill", "False"}, true);

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DatatableToDictionary(dt, "ID"));
```

And the result:

```
{
  "ID1": {
    "Name": "John",
    "Active": "True"
  },
  "ID2": {
    "Name": "Bill",
    "Active": "False"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, great helper method! thanx for the complete example.

Answer (score 1):

Using JSON.NET (`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`)

```
var obj = new JObject(
    dataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
         .Select(r => new JProperty(r["ID"].ToString(),
                 new JObject(
                     new JProperty("Name", r["Name"].ToString()),
                     new JProperty("Active", r["Active"].ToString())
                 )
             ))
);

// Convert the JObject to a JSON string
var json = obj.ToString();
```