# Convert datatable to json and bind in aspx for controls

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, datatable

I have a `datatable` object which returns me 1 one based on some condition. What I want is, I want to fill those `datatable` values in the control from the `aspx` side. For that I want to convert those datatable into `json`. How to convert it and bind to the aspx page?

Here is the code I tried:

```
protected void GET_VSAT_FORM_DATA(string SapId, string CandidateId)
{ 
    try
    {
        DataTable dtGetData = new DataTable();
        CommonDB CDB = new CommonDB();
        dtGetData = CDB.GET_VSAT_DATA(SapId, CandidateId);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {   
        throw;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
<span>CIRCLE :</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtCircle" style="width: auto;" readonly="true" />
    <br />

    <span>CANDIDATE ID :</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtCandidate" style="width: auto;" readonly="true" />
    <br />

    <span>SITE ID :</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtSiteId" style="width: auto;" readonly="true" />
    <br />

    <span>PRIORITY ID :</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtPriority" style="width: auto;" readonly="true" />
    <br />

    <span>SITE NAME :</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtSiteName" style="width: auto;" readonly="true" />
    <br />

    <span>SAP ID :</span>
    <input type="text" id="txtSapId" style="width: auto;" readonly="true" />
    <br />
```

Comment: you can do something like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138035/convert-datatable-to-json-with-key-per-row#answers-header

Comment: @Dot_NETPro: while installing `JSON.NET` i am getting installation error as `'Newtonsoft.Json' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'.`

Comment: @Dot_NETPro: Resolved that issue and converted into `json`. now how to bind it in aspx side?

Comment: How you want your data to be displayed? Like table? Like list?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: Hi Chetan, i want to bind it to the controls, which is in html format in the aspx side

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert datatable to json string using json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979922/how-to-convert-datatable-to-json-string-using-json-net)

Comment: @VDWWD: i have one more requirement here on how to bind it to html controls ? please let me know how to achieve that.

Comment: Why? you can bind a datatable to Controls directly. This sounds like databinding with extra steps. And to "bind" json as you put it you need javascript/jquery.

Comment: @VDWWD: i have no idea how to bind. please let me know if you have any clue, it would be great.

Comment: You use jquery/javascript for that. There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below method for convert dataTable to JSON, [Source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9bff34/3-ways-to-convert-datatable-to-json-string-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/)

```
public string DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(DataTable table) 
{  
      JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();  
      List < Dictionary < string, object >> parentRow = new List < 
      Dictionary < string, object >> ();  
      Dictionary < string, object > childRow;  
      foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows) 
      {  
         childRow = new Dictionary < string, object > ();  
         foreach(DataColumn col in table.Columns) 
         {  
              childRow.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col]);  
         }  
         parentRow.Add(childRow);  
      }  

     return jsSerializer.Serialize(parentRow);  
}
```

this will return you the JSON string.place above method in some where else in your class and just call below method like this

```
var convertedJSON = DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer(dtGetData);
```

Comment: my method is protected. Do I need to create another method and return it ?

Comment: i mean how to call `DataTableToJSONWithJavaScriptSerializer` in my `GET_VSAT_FORM_DATA` method ?

Comment: good one shakir, Now variable `convertedJSON`. how to use this to bind the control from aspx side.. any idea?

Comment: I mean, suppose I have one textbox with this variable. one of those values I want to fill with that textbox. how will I do this ?

Comment: The text box is a server control or html input control?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: it is an html control

Comment: @ShakirAhamed: i have updated my question for html part. and which `script` you are talking about ?

Comment: @ShakirAhamed Please do specify the source from where you have copied the code, credit to the original author:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9bff34/3-ways-to-convert-datatable-to-json-string-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/

Comment: @Dot_NETPro, I have already specified the source please check