# How can we find the expected table row while converting the json data into a datatable

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I know how to convert a json data into datatable, here I need to know if there is any formula to get the expected datatable row without actually converting the json into datatable.

Comment: I think this is helpful for you. [show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138035/convert-datatable-to-json-with-key-per-row)

Comment: it would be very helpful to edit you question with the additional information of the bounty (getting memory exceptions etc.)

Comment: there will be a lot of very similar questions in SO, please check and the links included there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747477/how-to-parse-huge-json-file-as-stream-in-json-net for processing huge JSONs as a stream and other workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

as already commented, parse the big JSON as a stream to handle huge amounts.
Then it's up to you to count the rows or process it to DataTables without memory exceptions:

```
using (FileStream s = File.Open("big.json")) // or any other stream
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(s))
using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;
    int rowCount = 0;
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            DataRow r = serializer.Deserialize<Contact>(reader);
            rowCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to deserialize the current row (which you are doing via `DataRow r = serializer.Deserialize<Contact>(reader);`).  You just need to *skip it* so that child objects are not counted as table rows.  [`JsonReader.Skip()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Skip.htm) should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using `JObject` using this way

```
        string jsonData = "";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("big.json"))
        {
            jsonData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
        }
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
        var results = o["datatable"].Where(x => (bool)x["filter"]).ToArray();
```