# Retrieve specific row from a Datatable in using c#

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, datatable

I created a datatable in my application

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
```

It has the following format

```
    ID    |  Name     |  Add    |   Edit  | View   | Authorize
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    10    | User      | true    |  trues  | trues  |  true
    11    | Group     | true    |  trues  | trues  |  true
    12    | Permission| true    |  trues  | trues  |  true
```

I want to retrieve one row from this datatable by id.

For example I want to retrieve the row with `id = 12`

That is,

```
  12    | Permission| true    |  trues  | trues  |  true
```

After that I want to convert only this row to json string using json.net

```
{["id":"12","name":"Permission","add":true,"edit":true,"authorize":true,"view":true}]
```

Is it possible? Please help

Comment: Yes, it's very possible. What have you tried? What web framework do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use LINQ and [Json.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).
At the top your class add:

```
using System.Linq;
```

In your code, you may have 2 approaches:

```
// 1. select the row in the table
// 2. create an anonymous object
// 3. serialize it
var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table.Select("ID=12")
    .Select(row => new
    {
        id = row["ID"],
        name = row["Name"],
        add = row["Add"],
        edit = row["Edit"],
        view = row["View"],
        authorize = row["Authorize"]
    }).FirstOrDefault());

// 1. cast all rows in the table
// 2. create a collection of anonymous objects
// 3. select the anonymous object by id
// 4. serialize it
var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(table .Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => new
    {
        id = row["ID"],
        name = row["Name"],
        add = row["Add"],
        edit = row["Edit"],
        view = row["View"],
        authorize = row["Authorize"]
    })
    .FirstOrDefault(row => row.id.ToString() == "12"));
```

Alternatively, you may use your own class. This option doesn't necessarily requires LINQ:

```
// 1. select the row
// 2. create a new TableRow object
// 3. serialize it
var filteredRow = table.Select("ID=12");
if (filteredRow.Length == 1)
{
    var json3 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        new TableRow(filteredRow[0].ItemArray));
}
```

A simplified `TableRow` class definition might look as the following:

```
public class TableRow
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool add { get; set; }
    public bool edit { get; set; }
    public bool view { get; set; }
    public bool authorize { get; set; }

    public TableRow(object[] itemArray)
    {
        id = Int32.Parse(itemArray[0].ToString());
        name = itemArray[1].ToString();
        add = bool.Parse(itemArray[2].ToString());
        edit = bool.Parse(itemArray[3].ToString());
        view = bool.Parse(itemArray[4].ToString());
        authorize = bool.Parse(itemArray[5].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it shows the error "Cast is not a member of System.Data.DataRowCollection"

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of `DataTable`

```
DataRow[] dr = table.Select("id = 12");
```

Or to be dynamic

```
int rowid = ... //assign some value through code and then
DataRow[] dr = table.Select("id = " + rowid);
```

I have no idea about JSON but you can look at

[Convert DataTable to JSON with key per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138035/convert-datatable-to-json-with-key-per-row)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/624888/Converting-DataTable-to-JSON-Format-in-Csharp-and

[C# DataTable to Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326777/c-sharp-datatable-to-json)

Comment: can i convert this datarow to json String?